# How to handle an exception (fatal error encountered during command execution)

Tags: vb.net

I have my code which is returning a fatal error during command execution. I am using xampp and VB.NET. I declared my command in a `Public Sub Execute`.  On another form with a different table in the same database, the code is saving data.  So I've same format of code with different forms but the code works with one form and the remaining forms return fatal error during command execution.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class UserRegistratioForm

    Dim con As New MySqlConnection(ConString)
    Public Sub execute(ByVal query As String)

        Dim command As New MySqlCommand(query, con)

        With command.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("@NationalID", NationalIDTextBox.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@Name", NameTextBox.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@BOB", DOBTextBox.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@Address", AddressTextBox.Text)
        End With

        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Sub

    Private Sub RegisterButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RegisterButton.Click

        Dim insert As String = "insert into users(NationalID,Name,DOB,Address) Values(@NationalID,@Name,@DOB,@Address)"

        Try
            con.Open()

            execute(insert)

            MessageBox.Show("User Registration Succeeded !")
            AdminSelection.Show()
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The code has `.AddWithValue("@BOB"` but it's `@DOB` elsewhere. Also, just so you know: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: Is NationalID a string type (VarChar or NVarChar) in the database? Is DataOfBirth a string type? It should be a Date type in the database. Make sure you are sending the correct types and use .Add method with the database type.

Comment: NationalID is a string

Comment: Thanks let me try this

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the problem and the best way I solved the issue is, I stopped using the
`command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter",parameterTextbox.Text)`
and I used
`command.Parameters.Add("@parameter",MysqlDbType.DataType).value=parameterTextbox.Text`
The code is now working perfectly.